# How do I write a an index(concatenate) function in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, concatenation

First, I know this topic is widely posted, and I've viewed 12+ hours of examples and I can't quite get this to work.  I'm trying to concatenate a path\filename\sheet\cell to reference when the workbook is closed.  Indirect works but only when the workbook is open.  Relative to many of the examples found, this is a seemingly simple one.

This works independently of CONCATENATE

```
=INDEX('C:\temp\[ABC.xlsx]Sheet1'!A:C,2,2)
```

This works independently of INDEX.  The filename "ABC" is found in cell "A2"

```
=CONCATENATE("'C:\temp\[",A2,".xlsx]Sheet1'!A:C")
```

The combination of INDEX and CONCATENATE yields "#VALUE!

```
=INDEX(CONCATENATE("'C:\temp\[",A2,".xlsx]Sheet1'!A:C"),2,2)
```

Basically, I'm trying to reference cell B2 in a file named ABC.xlsx in worksheet "Sheet1".  This above combination is what I need to work correctly.

Comment: I think I see what the problem is but I haven't figured out how to solve it yet.  If you look at the combined INDEX formula, you will see that there are quotes around your file path

Comment: looks like you are trying to use `indirect` but if I recall correctly, indirect cannot be used with  closed workbooks.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a great deal of effort on this, I believe that it may not be possible to do exactly what you want to do.  This is close though -- the value will update when the other file is closed.  However, it will not update real-time as the value is changed.

```
=INDEX('C:\temp\[&A2&.xlsx]Sheet1'!A:C,2,2)
```